# Google Cloud SDk: Python was not found

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

After I install Google cloud sdk in my computer, I open the terminal and type "gcloud --version" but it says "python was not found"

note:
I unchecked the box saying "Install python bundle" when I install Google cloud sdk because I already have python 3.10.2 installed.

so, how do fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend selecting the bundled Python version.  Otherwise, you will need to figure out what is wrong with your path environment variable. Your question lacks details such as OS, Python installation, etc.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I'm Using windows 11 and what do you mean by "python installation"?

Comment: You said you already have Python installed. However, the CLI cannot find it. Save yourself the headaches and reinstall the CLI selecting **install Python bundle**.

Comment: Before you go the route of reinstalling, first try the option of creating the environment variable - ```CLOUDSDK_PYTHON``` and point it to your ```Python3 installation```

Comment: @FariyaRahmat Thanks for your reply but I already reinstall the google cloud sdk with python bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [document](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install-sdk#windows):

> Cloud SDK requires Python; supported versions are Python 3 (preferred,
> 3.5 to 3.8) and Python 2 (2.7.9 or later). By default, the Windows version of Cloud SDK comes bundled with Python 3 and Python 2. To use
> Cloud SDK, your operating system must be able to run a supported
> version of Python.

As suggested by @John Hanley the CLI cannot find Python which is already installed. Try reinstalling the CLI selecting **install Python bundle**. If you are still facing the issue another workaround can be to try with Python version 2.x.x .

You can follow the below steps :

1.Uninstall all Python version 3 and above.

2.Install Python version -2.x.x (I have installed - 2.7.17)

3.Create environment variable - CLOUDSDK_PYTHON and provide value as C:\Python27\python.exe

4.Run GoogleCloudSDKInstaller.exe again.

Comment: Currently supported version are 3.8 - 3.12. I wouldn't uninstall Python 3 if you already use for loads of other things. Just set the environment variable and restart the terminal.

Answer (score 15):

On Windows, setting the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable fixes this, but when I first tried this I pointed the variable to the folder containing the python executable and that didn't work. The variable apparently must point to the executable file. [image]

Comment: Is adding this to the system variables enough or should I edit the "path" variable also in some way? Oh it was enough with just adding as a new variable, but I had to restart the terminal (in my case git bash)

Answer (score 10):

On ubuntu Linux, you can define this variable in the `.bashrc` file:

```bash
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The only missing aspect is the Windows setup, which is provided by another (later) answer. For Powershell add `$env:CLOUDSDK_PYTHON="C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe"` to the `$PROFILE` script (use the right python path, of course).